# Matching unique identifiers between two files of different length, line by line. Is there a better way to write this? [python]

Tags: python, parsing

```
bed = WRDIR + "AGGCAGAA_mm9_AlignedSorted_final_nameSorted_uniq.bed"
sam = WRDIR + "AGGCAGAA_bcs_nameSorted.sam"
out = WRDIR + "AGGCAGAA_joined.txt"

with open(bed) as b, open(sam) as s, open(out, 'w') as o:
    for x, b_line in enumerate(b, start=1):
        b_line = b_line.strip().split("\t")
        b_id = b_line[9]
        match_line = 1
        if x < 200: # for testing because file is huge..
            for s_line in s:
                s_line= s_line.strip().split("\t")
                s_id = s_line[0]
                if b_id == s_id:
                    output = b_id + "\tGENE:" + b_line[4] + "\tACC:" + b_line[5] + "\tCHR:" + b_id[6] + "\tBC:" + s_line[9][:12] + "\tUMI:" + s_line[9][12:] + "\n"
                    o.write(output)
                    match_line+=1
                    print "MATCH: (BED line " + str(x) + ")\t" + b_id + "\t\t(SAM line " + str(match_line) + ")\t" + s_id
                    break
                match_line+=1
```

**What is this script suppose to do?** It's suppose to look at two tab-delimited files which are sorted by a unique identifier in each file. The `bed` file is essentially a subset of the `sam` file. If this unique identifier matches between both files, then get data from the lines for which they match and write that information out to a file. Once this is done we move to the next line of `bed` and continue where we left off in `sam` (essentially working down the file).

I think this code does what it's intended to but there are a few bugs. `match_line` is suppose to be the line number of the second file but this is not the case. It seems to be effected by the break such that when the break is hit, the variable re-initializes at 1 (*I think*). The `output` variable is a line of tab-separated data that I'd like to write out to a file. I'm also not sure if this is the correct use of a break.

Next steps: This script only accounts for 1 set of files for a sample. There are essentially 9 samples, with each containing two species-specific files. E.g.:

```
samples = [
    "AGGCAGAA",
    "CAGAGAGG",
    "CGTACTAG",
    "CTCTCTAC",
    "GCTACGCT",
    "GGACTCCT",
    "TAAGGCGA",
    "TAGGCATG",
    "TCCTGAGC"
]

for idx, s in enumerate(samples, start=1):
    if idx == 1: ## TESTING

        print "Processing: %s (%s/%s)" % (s, str(idx), str(len(samples)))

        for sp in ["mm9", "hg19"]:
            # if sp == "mm9": ## TESTING

                bed = WRDIR + s + "_" + sp + "_AlignedSorted_final_nameSorted.bed"
                sam = WRDIR + s + "_bcs_nameSorted.sam"
                out = WRDIR + s +"_joined.txt"
```

I've quickly tired to integrate this into the script but received an error stating: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'file' objects.`

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Your code does not work as posted, after the first  `for s_line in s:` you have exhausted the iterator

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It seems to write out correctly. It does not print the correct line number of the match in `s` though. What is meant by exhausting the iterator. Is there a way to fix this line number issue?

Comment: For every line in `b`, you iterate over the file object s, after you have done that once, you have nothing left to iterate over, you need to add a, `s.seek(0)` but really a dict or a set would be a better approach once the data is not too large to store in memory